# How to match "^" symbol in awk using regular expressions within an if statement?

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I want to use regular expressions in an awk script to match symbols like ^, and perform certain operations when they match within an if statement.

However, I have tried increasing the number of backslashes in MARK="\^" or using MARK="^", but I still can't get a match.

Are there any other possible causes to consider?

```
MARK="^"

awk ~~~
if (mark ~ "['$MARK}']+") {
            print $1;
}
```

I tried to escape it with a backslash and expected it to match.

Comment: You say "symbols like ^" - different characters need different escaping if you want them to be treated literally (most should be put inside a bracket expression but, generally, `^` and ```\``` should be preceded by a ```\```), but in your code you're trying to escape a character to make it literal in a regexp comparison (`mark ~ ...`) which is usually a bad idea vs doing a string comparison (`mark == ...` or `index(mark,...)`) so I suspect that's not what your real code does. If you post a more realistic [mcve] of your real problem then we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an "if" here, a pattern is enough. Also, `[^]` might not work (it doesn't in gawk), you need to escape the caret:

```
mark=^
echo $'a\nb\nq^x\nd' | awk '(/\'"$mark"'/){print}'
```

Comment: Awk does have an `if` statement, though the OP's code does not look like a valid Awk script.

Comment: Well, `if` can only be used inside a block, a pattern is enough here.

Comment: Why wouldn't `[^]` work? It should always match a literal caret anywhere in the line. BTW, a caret on the start of the line could be matched by `^^` . For instance, `echo ^x | awk '/^^/ { print }'` prints _^x_.

Comment: @user1934428 I might be wrong but AFAIK `[^]` is undefined behavior per POSIX since `^` as the first char in a bracket expression is defined to mean the negation of the subsequent list inside that bracket expression, but it's not defined as meaning a literal `^` if there is no subsequent list, even if logically that'd make sense.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, don't let shell variables expand to become part of the body of the awk script (`/\'"$mark"'/`) or it can lead to complexity and/or cryptic errors. See [how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script), e.g. try that with `mark='"'`.

Comment: @EdMorton-SOstopbullying : You are right, that [the POSIX specs](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03_05) seem to have forgotten about this case. If the `^`  would mean inversion here too, the meaning would be _every character except those in the following empty list_, i.e. _every character is permitted_, and hence `[^]` would be equivalend to `.`. Indeed, _gawk_ seems to take this interpretation, since `echo x | gawk '/[^^]/ { print }'` matches ......

Comment: @user1934428 `[^^]` is defined, it means `every character except ^`. In gawk `[^]` would result in an "unterminated regexp" error (I just tried it with gawk 5.2.1) since it'd treat `]` as the first char in a negated char list inside an expected bracket expression, not the end of the bracket expression.

Comment: Ah right, my typo. If I do a `gawk '/[^]/ { print }'`, I get an _unterminated regexp_, because the first caret is taken as a negation, and the `]`, being the first element in the list, is taken literally. Hence the bracketed expression is not closed. BTWI can read **this** behaviour from the POSIX specs, and therefore I would say that the behaviour is defined:. choroba is right in that `[^]` can't work.

Comment: We could also read other behavior from the POSIX specs though, as you previously described, which is why I'd say it's undefined. I wouldn't be surprised if different awks did different things with it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried matching it using its ASCII code?

`\x5E`

Comment: unescaped `\x` doesn't work :::: `echo 'abc123xyz' | gawk '/\x5E/'` ::::::>    
`abc123xyz` ::::::::::::::: `gawk '/\\x5E/'` fixes that, but that's so verbose might as well just `gawk '/\^/'`

Answer (score 1):

Given:

```
cat file
Line 1
Line^2
Line 3
```

You can use a pattern with `^` escaped as so:

```
awk '/\^/' file 
Line^2
```

To use a *dynamic* regex with the specific meta character of `^` you need to do some escaping gymnastics.

This works:

```
mark='\\^'
awk -v m="$mark" '$0~m' file
# Line^2
```

Or this:

```
mark='^'
awk -v m="$mark" 'BEGIN{pat="\\" m}
$0~pat' file
# same
```

This is covered [HERE](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Computed-Regexps.html) in the GNU awk manual.

Simpler still is just use `index`:

```
mark='^'
awk -v m="$mark" 'index($0,m)' file
```

Which will find the literal `^` without any escaping.

Answer (score 1):

Without more info on what you're trying to do, you should not escape metachars to make a regexp metachar behave like a literal char in a regexp comparison, i.e. enhance this:

```
if (mark ~ "['$MARK}']+") {
            print $1;
}
```

you should just do a literal string comparison instead:

```
if ( index(mark,"'"$MARK"'") ) {
            print $1;
}
```

but you also should not let shell variables expand to become part of the body of an awk script, see [How do I use shell variables in an awk script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script), so you should be doing this or similar:

```
awk -v m="$MARK" '{
    .... whatever populates "mark" ....
    if ( index(mark,m) ) {
                print $1;
    }
}'
```